# Creating table on Oracle Db by Entity Framework 6 effect table name string format

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, plsqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am not sure how the title could be for this question but I am encounter weird problem. I am using EF 6 with Code First Approach on Oracle DB 12c by using provider Oracle.ManagedDataAccess. My entity classes are created by their default name on Db. For example, `User` => `Users`, `Role` => `Roles`. When I try to query to table on PL/SQL Developer tool like

```
select * from Users t
```

there will be error like

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

even table is filled. It means "there is no table or view". After trying lot of ways, I found that if I query like

```
select * from "Users" t
```

I can reach data now. So the questions are "why does it happen?", "what effects this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to Oracle naming rules. SQL is case-insensitive language, so when you write

```
select * from Users
```

Oracle understands this as

```
select * from USERS
```

But at the same time, Oracle allows you to create tables with unusual names, which have to be inside qoute marks. To query this table you need to write its name as in the `create table` statement. Here is a script for SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> create table "My Table with WEIRD Name" (id number);

Table created.

SQL> select * from "My Table with WEIRD Name";

no rows selected
```

Such names are case-sensitive, and, as I can guess, Entity Framework creates such names. Names `USERS` and `"USERS"` are equivalent, names `USERS` and `"Users"` - not. That's why your query works as

```
select * from "Users"
```

More information is in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51130).

Comment: This is my first project with Oracle. I thought it would be Entity Framework Code First but now I see what's going on. You are right about EF is creating  unusual name for Oracle Db. I also realized that Visual Studio Server Explorer queries to Oracle with table name within qoute marks.